# Embedded JS (ejs) isn't rendering data to browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pg-promise, embedded-javascript

I'm working on a simple To Do app using `express, node, pg-promise, and ejs.` I created a database and I can't get the contents to show up in the browser.

The weird thing is that when I inspect the browser it recognizes the shape of each task, but they're empty except for the `<p>` tags. The `<h1>` tags and content shows up so I thought it was a flounder/squid issue, but I'm not so sure.

The json data showed up, but after switching to response.render and linking the index.ejs file I haven't had any luck.

Here's a basic overview of the file structure:

```
1. models
   - task.js
2. views
   - edit.ejs
   - index.ejs
   - new.ejs
   - show.ejs
3. server.ejs, package.json, form.html
```

---

Database name: todo_app

Table name: tasks

```
id | subject  |             content
----+----------+---------------------------------
  1 | planning | plot world domination
  2 | garden   | find victims for venus fly trap
  3 | food     | buy pickles
  4 | postman  | test post
```

NOTE: Number 4 I added with Postman.

---

index.ejs

```
<body>
  <h1>Here's the task list:</h1>
  <% tasks.forEach((everyTask) => {%>
    <p>
      <%= tasks.content %>
    </p>
    <%})%>
</body>

</html>
```

---

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// const models = require('./models/task')

app.use(bodyParser.json())

const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

const findAllTasks = require('./models/task').findAllTasks;
const findById = require('./models/task').findById;
const createTask = require('./models/task').createTask;
// const edit = require('./models/task').edit;
// const delete = require('./models/task').delete;


app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  findAllTasks().then(everyTask => {
    response.render('index', { tasks: everyTask });
  });
});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Welcome to the Year ${PORT}, the world of tomorrow!`)
});
```

---

task.js

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')({});

const connectionURL = "postgres://localhost:5432/todo_app";

const db = pgp(connectionURL);

const findAllTasks = () => {
  return db.any('SELECT * FROM tasks');
}

const findById = id => {
  return db.one('SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE id = $1', [id]);
};

const createTask = data => {
  return db.one('INSERT INTO tasks(subject, content) VALUES($[subject], $[content]) RETURNING id', data)
}

module.exports = {
  findAllTasks: findAllTasks,
  findById: findById,
  createTask: createTask
  // edit: edit,
  // delete: delete
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with `task.ejs` you mean: `index.ejs`. and your forEach should be like the following:

```
<body>
  <h1>Here's the task list:</h1>
  <% tasks.forEach((everyTask) => {%>
    <p>
      <%= everyTask.content %>
    </p>
    <%})%>
</body>
```

Comment: You're right, it's index.ejs. Also, everyTask worked! I was pretty sure the forEach was supposed to reference findAllTasks in the server.js file, so it's the findAllTasks that I was focusing on. Thanks!